# Sorting the distance values in an ascending order in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have an application that shows some spots on the map, I want to find the nearest 3 spots by sorting the distance in ascending order, here is the distance code:

```
CLLocation *thePoint = ([[CLLocation alloc]initWithLatitude:[spot.LocationLat doubleValue] longitude:[spot.LocationLong doubleValue]]);
         CLLocationDistance dist = [thePoint distanceFromLocation:currentLocation];
NSLog(@"%f",dist);
```

Comment: Where's the array? What's in the array?

Comment: sorry i meant the distance values

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:nil ascending:YES];

[array sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor]];
```

array should be a NSMutableArray

Answer (score 0):

Well, lot of ambiguity in your question. Assuming you know your reference point and three points around it from which you want to calculate the shortest distance:

```
NSMutableArray *distanceArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:3];
NSMutableDictionary *points = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithCapacity:3];

// First Point Distance
CLLocation *firstPoint = ([[CLLocation alloc]initWithLatitude:[firstSpot.LocationLat doubleValue] longitude:[firstSpot.LocationLong doubleValue]]);
NSNumber *firstPointDistance = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:[firstPoint distanceFromLocation:currentLocation]];
[distanceArray addObject:firstPointDistance];
[points setObject:firstPointDistance forKey:firstPoint];

// Second Point Distance
CLLocation *secondPoint = ([[CLLocation alloc]initWithLatitude:[secondSpot.LocationLat doubleValue] longitude:[secondSpot.LocationLong doubleValue]]);
NSNumber *secondPointDistance = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:[secondPoint distanceFromLocation:currentLocation]];
[distanceArray addObject:secondPointDistance];
[points setObject:secondPointDistance forKey:secondPoint];

// Third Point Distance
CLLocation *thirdPoint = ([[CLLocation alloc]initWithLatitude:[thirdSpot.LocationLat doubleValue] longitude:[thirdSpot.LocationLong doubleValue]]);
NSNumber *thirdPointDistance = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:[thirdPoint distanceFromLocation:currentLocation]];
[distanceArray addObject:thirdPointDistance];
[points setObject:thirdPointDistance forKey:thirdPoint];

// Shortest distance & point
NSArray *sortedDistanceArray = [distanceArray sortedArrayUsingComparator:^ NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {
                                return [obj2 compare:obj1];
                            }];

NSLog(@"Shortest distance = %@ from point = %@", sortedDistanceArray[0], points[sortedDistanceArray[0]]);
```

Comment: it's too big and lots of unneeded information, and i want all the points' distances to be found then finding the minimum 3

Comment: the problem is the type of my distance is CLLocationDistance

Comment: CLLocationDistance is nothing but a double. You can easily convert it in NSNumber as I did in my post. Check it out. `[NSNumber numberWithDouble:[thirdPoint distanceFromLocation:currentLocation]`